# Create entities from exitsting database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a database with prefix on the table. Usually i do

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundle yml
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle
```

but with the prefix im getting Entities like

**PrefixUser**

instead of

**User**

Is it an option to solve this?

Comment: No. There is no such options doctrine will generate you entity like table name. You have to change this by hand.

Comment: Bummer. But thanks anyway!